# React Bootstrap NavBar Container, set width to auto

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, navbar, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use a NavBar from react bootstrap. However there seems to be a `<div class="container">` that adds `width`. How do I set this `width` to `auto`?

[image]

I tried the following:

```
.navbar > .container {
    width:auto;
}
```

But this margin still remains. I also tried to

```
<Navbar style={{ width: "auto" }}>
    <Navbar.Header>
       ...
```

But no success. My complete code:

```
<Row>
    <Navbar>
        <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand className="lang-de">
                <a href="/" />
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav pullRight>
                <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
                    Impressum
                </NavItem>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use only React Bootstrap **Fixed top**

```
<Navbar fixed="top" />
```

It will auto create the CSS below:

```
.fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

You can see the this and another positions in documentation [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the grid system you can set the Container to fluid

```
       <Container fluid>
          <NavBar />
          <Row>
              <div>Personal Digital Assistants</div>
              <ProfileCard text="Hello" info='unknown' imageTag={AlexaImg}/>
              <ProfileCard text="Sir" info='unknown' imageTag={CortanaImg}/>
              <ProfileCard text="Google thing" info='known' imageTag={SiriImg}/>
          </Row>
      </Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css, try the following:

```
.navbar > .container {
    width:auto!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "fluid" next to Navbar on your code

```
<Row>
<Navbar fluid>
    <Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Brand className="lang-de">
            <a href="/" />
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav pullRight>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
                Impressum
            </NavItem>
        </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add container props to Navbar component and these all value you can pass to container props, container, container="fluid", container="sm" or md, lg, xl or xxl.

```
<Navbar color="light" light expand="md" container>
```